# neo4J - sandbox doesn't work?

Tags: neo4j

I've been fooling with neo4j:

however, it appears the **sandbox** feature is just completely broken?

simply click here

https://auth.neo4j.com/index-sandbox-v2.html#

or perhaps https://auth.neo4j.com/index-sandbox.html#

create an act with your email (or Google/etc);

it just doesn't work - it spins forever:

[image]

Am I making some basic mistake?

Comment: any neo4jers out there?!  :)

Comment: Have you registered?  Try a different browser too just to rule it out.

Comment: thanks @wBob  -for sure I registered, and, unfortunately tried a number of browsers.  If you click on it just now do you get the same ??

Comment: Hmm, I can repro this on IE11 but after registering, verifying my email address and accepting cookies, I seem to be able to login.  Try this in Chrome?  https://neo4j.com/sandbox-v2/#

Comment: thank you so much for that report @wBob - perhaps you should pop it in as an answer to get points!

Comment: Did it help you?

Comment: hey @wBob, for sure, I voted voted voted your helpful comments, thanks again so much.  I popped in an answer, as it may help any googlers.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear neo4J (well, the web site) was just totally broken for some days there (around Aug 7 2017).

As reported by wBob, it does seem to be working now!

It's worth noting that the basic problem (reported in the question above) seems to be resolved.  However, after you "create a sandbox" the system appears to fail when you "go to the data browser" in that sandbox ... but it would appear that it simply works after, say, a few minutes (there's no warning while it is getting going).

Once you get past all that it does seem to work, eg the "movie" sandbox:

[image]